# Flutter APP Crash on Android 10

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, crashlytics

Estoy realizando una app en flutter con firebase y en Android 9 funciona correctamente.

Al ejecutarlo en de Android 10 (tanto emulador como real) la aplicación crashea, he intentado muchas cosas pero no hay forma de que funcione.

Es mi primera aplicacion en flutter y al realizar el release no me iniciaba la aplicacion en mi samsung s21+, he descargado la sdk de android 10 en el emulador y sale la pantalla roja que se puede ver mas abajo....

No entiendo muy bien a que se refiere el error, ya que donde menciona que hay problemas no veo nada raro...

Cualquier aporte es de agradecer

**pubspect.yaml**

```
version: 1.0.2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.4
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.6
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/images/
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if(keystorePropertiesFile.exists()){
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.fruiteshurtosapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs{
        release{
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**doctor --verbose**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.18363.1440], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 2.0.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision adc687823a (5 days ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
    • Engine revision b09f014e96
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Dylan Garrido\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-S, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Dylan Garrido\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile)       • emulator-5556 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.72
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 88.0.705.63

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

*main.dart*

```
void main()async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool userIsLoggedIn = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    getLoggedInState();
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Emulador android 10 crash**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

creo que este error se debe al minSdkVersion, que se encuentra en el build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.fruiteshurtosapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Ultimamente se usa como versión mínima la 21, asi que te recomiento que cambies esa parte

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.fruiteshurtosapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```